# Authenticate User after cancels first prompt game center

Tags: ios, xcode, game-center

I’m using the tutorial at http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1

I have two issues I’ve been trying to work out.  The app works fine if the user is logged in.  I want to know how to recheck/ask about logging in if they decide to cancel the initial request.

This is in the appDelegate

```
  // At the top of the file
  #import "GCTurnBasedMatchHelper.h"

  // At the end of applicationDidFinishLaunching, right before 
  // the return YES
  [[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance] authenticateLocalUser];
```

I thought about doing this in the app....

```
    if([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].playerID]==nil)
    {
    [[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance] authenticateLocalUser];
    NSLog(@“Log them in!\n”);
    }
    else
    {
    NSLog(@“All set\n”);
    }
```

Apparently this isn’t the way to go...  How should I do this?

Comment: do you want to ask again right after the initial cancellation?

Comment: No not necessarily.  I’d like to create a method that I’ll call after a game is completed or when a button is pressed in case they wanted to change their mind later.

Answer (score 0):

I would make a function like that :

```
-(void)autentificateAgain{
    [[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance] authenticateLocalUser];
}
```

Now call it from a button...
That should do the trick.

I hope it helps :-)

Greetings

Anselm

Comment: Yea I tried that... it doesn’t work.  I”m not sure what “sharedInstance” means either.

Comment: the sharedInstance is probably referring to a singleton in your gamekit helper class...